# Transcendental numbers are decidable: a proof?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, decidability, algebraic-numbers

My opinion is that the statement, for a real number $X$:

"$X$ is transcendental."

is decidable.
The sketch of the "proof" should be the following.
If transcendency or algebraicity of $X$ is undecidable in a theory O, then we could derive two new different theories A and B:

- X is algebraic in A, so a polynomial with integer coefficients $P(x)$ exists, and $X$ is a zero of it;
- X is transcendental in B, so no polynomial P(X) exists with X zero;

But we know that the set of the polynomials with integer coefficients is countable, so a complete list of such polynomials exists.
So, how is it possible that in theory A a polynomial $P$ is present, but $P$ is NOT present in B?

In conclusion, because of the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients is countable, :

- OR such polynomial exists also in O (as well as in A), and then it is present also in B (and it should be a contradiction!), and X is algebraic,
- EITHER P does not exist at all, so it can not be present neither in A
  (another contradiction!), and X is transcendental.

So transcendence can not be considered undecidable, because its undecidability should lead to contradictions.

Is the sketch correct?

Comment: Given not only $X$ but also the polynomial $P$, is it certain that it's decidable whether $P(X)=0$?

Comment: How are you given $X$? Surely the actual description will affect whether transcendentalness is easy or hard.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It's semidecidable that $P(X)\neq 0$ for computable $X$ by using interval analysis, but of course that implies nothing about the decidability the other way.

Comment: Even if we ignore the difficulty to check whether a given number is a root of a given polynomial (this is only seems to be trivial , but a proof that it is a root will fail in general), we still have the problem that in the transcendental case , we cannot check all possible polynomials since there are infinite many.

Comment: If we know (for whatever reason) that the given number is uncomputable , we immediately know that it is transcendental since every algebraic number is computable.

Comment: To demonstrate your fallacy consider the halting problem : It is clear that a halting program will halt in a finite amount of time , so it seems that we can solve the halting problem by just letting the program run. But we cannot wait an eternity whether it halts , and in the case it does not, waiting will never lead to a result. The problem here is similar.